# React Redux - useState Hook not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have 2 actions in redux (both async) and I'm calling them both within my functional component via `dispatch`; the first using `useEffect` and the second via a button click. What I want to do is dispatch the actions to retrieve them from an async function, then use them within my component via `useState`. But using the `useState` is not rendering.

Here is my component:

```
export default function Hello()
{

  const { first, second } = useSelector(state => state.myReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const fetchFirst = async () => dispatch(getFirst());
  const fetchSecond = async () => dispatch(getSecond());
  const fetchFixturesForDate = (date: Date) => dispatch(getFixturesForDate(date));

  const [superValue, setSuperValue] = useState('value not set');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      fetchFirst();
      setSuperValue(first);
    };

    fetch();
  }, []);

  const getSecondOnClickHandler = async () =>
  {
    console.log('a')
    await fetchSecond();
    setSuperValue(second);
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <p>The super value should first display the value "first item" once retrieved, then display "second value" once you click the button and the value is retrieved</p>
    <p>Super Value: {superValue}</p>
    <p>First Value: {first}</p>
    <p>Second Value: {second}</p>
    <button onClick={async () => await getSecondOnClickHandler()}>Get Second</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The `superValue` never renders even though I am setting it, although the value from `first` and `second` is retrieved and displayed.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ky4alk?file=Hello.tsx).

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `first` and `second` inside your two `useEffects` is set when the component mounts (I guess at that point they are undefined). So in both cases you will be setting `superValue` to that initial value.

You have two options:

1. Return the first/second values back from `fetchFirst` and `fetchSecond`, so that you can retrieve them directly from the executed function, and then set superValue:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      const newFirst = await fetchFirst();
      setSuperValue(newFirst);
    };

    fetch();
  }, []);
```

2. Add separate `useEffect`s that listen for changes to `first` and `second`

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setSuperValue(first)
  },[first])

  useEffect(() => {
    setSuperValue(second)
  },[second])
```

Comment: thank you! looks like I was using `useEffect` incorrectly!

Answer (score 1):

The value in the reducer is not necessarily set when the action is dispatched, e.g. after `fetchFirst()` is called. Also the `await` that you do in `await fetchSecond();`
doesn't help since the reducer function is not executed.

You could add `useEffect` hooks and remove the `setSuperValue` from the other methods, but I think the code gets quite complicated.
What problem are you trying to solve in the first place?

```
 useEffect(() => setSuperValue(first), [first]);
 useEffect(() => setSuperValue(second), [second]);

useEffect(() => {
   const fetch = async () => {
     fetchFirst();
   };
   fetch();
 }, []);

 const getSecondOnClickHandler = async () => {
   console.log('a');
   await fetchSecond();
 };
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hsqd3x?file=Hello.tsx